# UINavigationbar with large titles pop back animation glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i have a view controller with large titles enabled and navigate to another view controller where large titles are disabled and has a uisearchcontroller attached to its navigation bar. When i pop back to previous controller there is a bad ui glitch where its very easy to spot and looks horrible. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

In the second view controller:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

[Link to the gif that shows the ui glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5kvG.gif)

Thanks everyone, i am open for ideas as well.

Comment: in which method you have wrote the code :'navigationController ? .navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
navigationItem.searchController = searchController'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your code in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. It will always handle the navigation animations and it's probably causing the glitch.

Comment: Yea, apparently i had some code that was related to navigation bar in view will appear which caused the issue. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 11):

In the second view controller instead of setting, `prefersLargeTitles = false` use the below code. This will fix the issue.

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```